# Did Vernor Vinge originate the euphemism "you-gotta-believe-me"?

Tags: vernor-vinge, charles-stross

Charles Stross's latest "Laundry series" novel, **The Rhesus Chart**, uses the phrase "you-gotta-believe-me" to refer to mind control powers. The first time I came across this was in Vinge's **Rainbow's End**, where he claimed it originated in a turn of the century novel, but didn't say which one. Does anyone know if this was an in-joke on Vinge's part, or if there was another novel that used this euphemism that both Stross and Vinge were inspired by?

Comment: Does he say it originated from a turn-of-the-century *novel*? Googling, all I find is this quote from *Rainbow's End*: "That was a bit of science-fiction jargon from the turn of the century: You-Gotta-Believe-Me. That is, mind control." The way it's phrased, he may just mean that in the context of his story, the popular phrase "you gotta believe me" was turned into a euphemism for mind control around the turn of the century, i.e. not too far into the 2000s.

Comment: Interesting.  I took "turn of the century" to mean around 1900.  (Since the book was written before 2000.)  But the book is set after 2000, so it may mean around 2000.  Maybe *Rainbows End* (note: no apostrophe) is the book that popularized the phrase...

Comment: I assumed this was a recursive joke - that the "turn-of-the-century" SF was itself some alternate reality Vinge novel, a counterpart to *Rainbows End*.